# I'm getting this error: Class "Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized" not found

Tags: php, magento2.4, zend-filter, php-8.2

Not sure if it has to do with php 8.2 specifically or just php 8. My exception log is saying that it's not found here in this file but below is the code from line(s) 190 - 197.  Checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php:191

```
    if (isset($params['qty'])) {
        $filter = new \Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
            ['locale' => $this->_objectManager->get(
                \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface::class
            )->getLocale()]
        );
        $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
    }
```

It was working in php 7.3 and so i honestly am not sure what it wants me to do here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what ended up working for me:

```
use Magento\Framework\Filter\LocalizedToNormalized;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface;


            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
            $filter = new LocalizedToNormalized(
                ['locale' => $this->_objectManager->get(
                    ResolverInterface::class
                )->getLocale()]
            );
            $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In version 2.4.6, `Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized` has been replacement with `Magento\Framework\Filter\LocalizedToNormalized` (try this class and everything will working).

I think the reason you get this error because you upgrade to version 2.4.6 but your module not compatible with magento 2.4.6 yet.

You can read about class change in `vendor/magento/magento-coding-standard/Magento2/Sniffs/Legacy/_files/restricted_classes.php` in line 282-285.

Comment: Yes @The LB, in my case this works fine.

"In version 2.4.6, Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized has been replacement with Magento\Framework\Filter\LocalizedToNormalized (try this class and everything will working)."

Comment: Just to be clear you meant change this:

Comment: if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = Magento\Framework\Filter\LocalizedToNormalized(
                    ['locale' => $this->_objectManager->get(
 like so?? @The LB

Comment: $filter = new \Magento\Framework\Filter\LocalizedToNormalized(...) like this. Just replace `Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized` with `Magento\Framework\Filter\LocalizedToNormalized`, everything else stays the same. @Singleton